# Override property with Derived class.

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to separate out a big classes I had into 3 separate classes:

A base class with shared functionality

A server class with server only functionality

A client class with client only functionality

The problem I'm having is I cannot overload properties with a derived class.

Below I've prepared a code sample of a base classes and their server counterparts.

I'm way off somewhere but I was expecting to be able to call "base class" functions and them to work with the overridden derived class.

```
public class Battlefield
{
    public Tile[,] Tiles { get; set; }
    public virtual Game Game { get; set; }

    public Battlefield(int sizeX, int sizeY, Game game)
    {
        Tiles = new Tile[sizeX, sizeY];
        Game = game;
    }

    public Tile GetTile(int x, int y)
    {
        return Tiles[x, y];
    }
}

public class ServerBattleField : Battlefield
{
    public override ServerGame Game  { get; set; }

    public ServerBattleField(int sizeX, int sizeY, ServerGame game) : base(sizeX, sizeY, game)
    {
    }

    public void DoSomethingServerSpecific()
    {
        Game.DoSomethingServerSpecialWithTile(10,5);
    }
}

public class Game
{
    public virtual Battlefield Battlefield {get;set;}

    public Game(int sizeX, int sizeY)
    {
        Battlefield = new Battlefield(sizeX,sizeY,this);
    }

    public void DoSomethingWithTile(int x, int y)
    {
        Battlefield.GetTile(x,y).DoSomethingWithTile();
    }


}

public class ServerGame : Game
{
    public override ServerBattleField Battlefield {get;set;}

    public ServerGame(int sizeX, int sizeY)
        : base(sizeX, sizeY)
    {
    }

    public void DoSomethingServerSpecialWithTile(int x, int y)
    {
        Battlefield.GetTile(x, y).DoSomethingWithTile();
        Battlefield.GetTile(x, y).DoSomethingSpecialWithTile();
    }

}

public class Tile {
    public void DoSomethingWithTile() { }
    public void DoSomethingSpecialWithTile() { }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ovveriden property *must* respect *exact* signature of the base class property.

In your specific case, you need

```
public class ServerBattleField : Battlefield
{
    public override ServerGame Game  { get; set; } //CHANGE TO RETURN TYPE GAME

    ....
}
```

like:

```
public class ServerBattleField : Battlefield
{
    public override Game Game  { get; set; } //CHANGE TO RETURN TYPE GAME

    ....
}
```

note that it overlaps with the property name itself: *not good*, better to change it to avoid future confusion in naming

Comment: Sorry I should have posted I see the error that they must match, I'm just not too sure how I should make it work.

Comment: If `ServerGame` inherits from `Game` you can still return an instance of `ServerGame`, but it will be returned as `Game`.

Comment: With your example, would that then not allow me to use functions that are declared within ServerGame without casting?

Comment: You can return an instance of ServerGame, as it's derived from Game it will be upper casted to base class type without a problem.

Comment: So would I need to use (ServerGame)Game within ServerBattlefield to use and of the functions / properties specified in ServerGame?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is as Tigran explained in the signature of the property. If you want to custom-type it per derived class you can use generics.

```
public class ServerBattleField : Battlefield<GameType>
{
}
```

Where `Battlefield` is:

```
public class Battlefield<T>
{
    public T Game { get; set; }
}
```

You could force `T` to derive from a base `Game` class or interface.

There is no need to derive that property any more.

Answer (score 1):

Using Generics is a good approach, your Battlefield classes will look like this:

```
public class Battlefield<T> where T: Game
{
    public Tile[,] Tiles { get; set; }
    public T Game { get; set; }

    public Battlefield(int sizeX, int sizeY, T game)
    {
        Tiles = new Tile[sizeX, sizeY];
        Game = game;
    }

    public Tile GetTile(int x, int y)
    {
        return Tiles[x, y];
    }
}

public class ServerBattleField : Battlefield<ServerGame> 
{

    public ServerBattleField(int sizeX, int sizeY, ServerGame game)
        : base(sizeX, sizeY, game)
    {
    }

    public void DoSomethingServerSpecific()
    {
        Game.DoSomethingServerSpecialWithTile(10, 5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot *overload* something that differs only by return type. Here's why:

```
ServerGame oServer = new ServerGame();
BattleField oBF = oServer.BattleField; //No way to know which BattleField property to return.
```

You can *override* something with an identical signature, and since `ServerBattleField` inherits from `BattleField`, there is no issue with return an object of type `ServerBattleField` from the `BattleField` property. The code that uses it will just have to know to cast it to the correct type if it needs `ServerBattleField` functionality specifically.

Also, note that any code that accesses `ServerGame`'s `BattleField` property, even though it's defined as returning a `BattleField` object, it **will** use the any derived class's overriden functionality.